# Disable kernel tracer

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 (32bit). The current tracer is set as nop.

```
cat current_tracer 
nop
```

Although the current tracer is nop, all these following messages are printing and continuously printed while I am performing other operations. **Why is this so happening ? How can I disable to print these messages being printed?**

```
<...>-573   [003] ....     6.304043: do_sys_open: "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-firewire.conf" 0 666
           <...>-573   [003] ....     6.304055: do_sys_open: "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf" 0 666
           <...>-569   [000] ....     6.304073: do_sys_open: "/run/udev/data/c4:73" 88000 666
           <...>-573   [003] ....     6.304077: do_sys_open: "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-modem.conf" 0 666
           <...>-573   [003] ....     6.304087: do_sys_open: "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-oss.conf" 0 666
           <...>-573   [003] ....     6.304119: do_sys_open: "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf" 0 666
           <...>-573   [003] ....     6.304135: do_sys_open: "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-watchdog.conf" 0 666
           <...>-573   [003] ....     6.304166: do_sys_open: "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf" 0 666
           <...>-569   [000] ....     6.304180: do_sys_open: "/run/udev/data/c4:73.tmp" 88241 666
           <...>-573   [003] ....     6.304190: do_sys_open: "/etc/modprobe.d/vmwgfx-fbdev.conf" 0 666
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There seems to be an explicit `trace_printk()` in the function `do_sys_open()`. Right?...

Comment: @TheCodeArtist, I haven't added trace_printk() statement in that function.I have just installed fresh in 3 different systems and in every system I am getting this messages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `echo 0 > tracing_on`?

Have you tried `echo notrace_printk > trace_options`?

However, if you are concerned about ftrace's overhead, you should do more than this and disable ftrace entirely.

If you are unsure of how to deal with ftrace, you can also look at the [`trace-cmd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/trace-cmd.1.html) command.

In particular, try `trace-cmd reset`.